# How can I disable popover in a GTK text_view on touchscreen?

Tags: c, gtk, touch, raspberry-pi3, gtk3

I am writing a Kiosk app for a Raspberry Pi with touchscreen. I am using GTK+3.22 and C. GTK's entry and text_view widgets works fine with the touchscreen, but it annoys me that popover seems to be enabled by default for these widgets. I only see popovers when I use the touchscreen, not when I use an ordinary screen and mouse.

In the GTK+3 manual there are functions for adding new popover widgets so I guess you can also destroy them if they have been added, but how can I get rid of the default popover, if I have not added it myself to my text_view widget? I have searched all over the Internet for this but haven't found an answer. I have seen that other applications developed with GTK also shows this behavior on my touchscreen.

Comment: Do you mean that mobile-like *cut copy paste* popover?

Comment: Yes, the "bubble" selection symbols pops up and also occasionally a larger square "icon" that might mean "paste".